# Alt+Tab causes applications switching in two layers

Tags: 16.04, unity, application-switcher

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.4. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> the application switcher GUI generates two layers of images.

[image: Problem Screenshoot]

How I can solve this problem?